# Why it is sufficient to look at prime divisor of $p-1$ when finding generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, finite-fields, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

Let's say that I want to find the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, where $p$ is a prime number. I found the following necessary and sufficient condition:

> An element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$
> if and only if $$x^{\frac{p-1}{t}} \neq 1, \text{ for every prime divisor t} \text{ of } p-1.$$

Why is this true? I mean, why it is enough to check for prime divisor of $p-1$ instead of for every $r$ such that $1 \leq r < p-1$ (that is, the definition of generator).

I have also found another necessary and sufficient condition regarding primitive $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ with the same problematic:

> Let $n$ be an integer such that $1 \leq n \leq p-1$.  An element $x
> > \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is a primite $n$-th root of unity in
> $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ if and only if $$x^{\frac{n}{t}} \neq 1, \text{ for every prime divisor t} \text{ of } n.$$

I suppose that answering the previous problematic would also solve this one.

Comment: Argue that:  If $x$ has order $\frac {p-1}d$ for some proper divisor $d$ of $p-1$, then let $q$ be any prime divisor of $d$.  Then $x^{(p-1)/q}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: By Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ (if $\gcd(a,p)=1$). So we know the order is a divisor of $p-1$, by Lagrange's Theorem. So it suffices to show it is not a *proper* divisor of $p-1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you mean that it suffices to show it is a *proper* divisor of $p-1$?

Comment: You are trying to show that the order is *exactly* $p-1$ (for it to be a primitive root/generator) so you want to show that the order is **not** a proper divisor of $p-1$.